# changing language from english to dutch

Tags: java, javafx

I would like to change the language of my App from english to dutch when I refresh my screen (java and javaFX). Does anyone know where to start or wether there is a function to change the language within an app?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java/

Comment: You need to externalize all your strings, and use something like thr i18n Manager to get the correct language. But usually you need to restart for change the locale

Answer (score 1):

You should put all the strings in properties files, using the naming mechanism described in the [`ResourceBundle` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle-java.lang.String-java.util.Locale-java.lang.ClassLoader-).

You can then create an `ObjectProperty<Locale>` to represent the current locale (i.e. language), and bind all the strings in your UI to the appropriate value based on this locale. You probably want a separate class to handle this: here's a simple example.

```
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.binding.StringBinding;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;

public class LocalizedBinding {

    // property representing the current locale:
    private final ObjectProperty<Locale> locale ;

    // private property to hold the resource bundle:
    private final ObjectProperty<ResourceBundle> bundle ;

    public LocalizedBinding(String bundleName, Locale locale) {

        this.locale = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(locale);
        this.bundle = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

        // update resource bundle whenever locale changes:
        bundle.bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> {
                Locale l = this.locale.get();
                if (l == null) {
                    return null ;
                } else {
                    ResourceBundle resources = ResourceBundle.getBundle(bundleName, l);
                    return resources;
                }
            },          
            this.locale));
    }   

    // creates a StringBinding whose value is obtained from the current
    // resource bundle using the provided key. The binding will automatically
    // update if the locale changes:

    public StringBinding createStringBinding(String key) {
        return new StringBinding() {

            {
                bind(bundle);
            }

            @Override
            protected String computeValue() {
                ResourceBundle resources = bundle.get();
                if (resources == null) {
                    return key ;
                } else {
                    return resources.getString(key);
                }
            }

        };
    }

    // Property accessors for locale:

    public final ObjectProperty<Locale> localeProperty() {
        return this.locale;
    }

    public final java.util.Locale getLocale() {
        return this.localeProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setLocale(final java.util.Locale locale) {
        this.localeProperty().set(locale);
    }
}
```

Here's a quick example using this:

```
import java.util.Locale;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SwitchableLanguageTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Combo box for language selection:
        ComboBox<Locale> combo = new ComboBox<>();
        combo.getItems().addAll(Locale.getDefault(), new Locale("nl"));

        // display each language in the actual language:
        combo.setCellFactory(lv -> createListCell());
        combo.setButtonCell(createListCell());

        Label greetingLabel = new Label();

        // Create a localizedBinding object for the bundle resources/greetings 
        LocalizedBinding localizedBinding = new LocalizedBinding(
                "resources/greetings", Locale.getDefault());

        // update the localizedBinding's locale when the combo box value changes:
        localizedBinding.localeProperty().bind(combo.valueProperty());

        // bind the label's text:
        greetingLabel.textProperty().bind(
                localizedBinding.createStringBinding("greeting"));

        combo.getSelectionModel().select(Locale.getDefault());

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(greetingLabel, combo, null, null, null);
        BorderPane.setAlignment(combo, Pos.CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private ListCell<Locale> createListCell() {
        return new ListCell<Locale>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(Locale locale, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(locale, empty);
                if (empty) {
                    setText("");
                } else {
                    setText(locale.getDisplayLanguage(locale));
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The two properties files (in the resources directory) are

greetings.properties:

```
greeting=Hello
```

and 
greetings_nl.properties:

```
greeting=Hallo
```