# Recalculate layout of buttons on a dynamic language change using ComboBox in FXML

Tags: java, javafx, internationalization, locale, fxml

I have a BorderPane where I have a TreeView (meny) on the left, mainPane (AnchorPane) on the right and toolbar on the top. I'm able to select a language from the ComboBox which is located on the toolbar and it changes the language to the selected one somewhat dynamically (Just needs an extra click on a random treeView item for some reason. This is also a problem I have but not my main issue concerning this question). However, when I change the language from the ComboBox, the layout stays the same on the mainPane and buttons, labels etc. overlap each other if a long language is selected (i.e Spanish). If I start the program with Spanish locale, then no problem, the layout is calculated accordingly.

I've read about Binding and checked other SO regarding this issue for ex. [changing language](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27193018/4944516). However, considering the amount of buttons, labels, etc. on each of my TreeView pages I have, it feels pretty overwhelming to me to bind each and every object in my case. Is there any other approach to this?

Comment: no, there is no build-in support for changing locales at runtime - you have to implement it yourself (yes, for each and every node that must be locale-aware). There might be third-party libs out in the wild (don't know). As to updating layout: might need a requestLayout on the scene root .. if that doesn't help, [mcve] please :)

Comment: try `primaryStage.sizeToScene();` after changing the locale heres what it does "Set the width and height of this Window to match the size of the content of this Window's Scene." this may not help at all but you haven't shown any code so really there not much anyone can do to help